# Behaviour of dynamic polymorphism using templates?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

A few years ago, during an interview I was shown some scary-looking code which had the same behaviour as dynamic polymorphism but used templates. I am not referring to normal usage of templates.

How can templates be used to implement behaviour equivalent to run-time polymorphism?

UPDATE: I think it was related to this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Static_polymorphism

Comment: They can't. They can however implement *static polymorphism* which may look similar. Take the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) for example.

Comment: In addition, the `any` object design pattern uses templates internally to create dynamic polymorphism that looks like duck typing.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Curiously Recurrent Template Pattern (CRTP) you could achieve something similar known as ***compile-time polymorphism***. Here is a simple example:

```
template<typename DERIVED>
struct base
{
public:
    void f() const
    {
        static_cast<DERIVED&>( *this ).f_();
    }
};

struct derived1 : public base<derived1>
{
    void f_() const
    {
        std::cout << "Derived1!\n";
    }
};

struct derived2 : public base<derived2>
{
    void f_() const
    {
        std::cout << "Derived2!\n";
    }
};

template<typename DERIVED>
void call( const base<DERIVED>& e )
{
    e.f(); //compile-time resolved (Possibly inlined) polymorphic call here
}

int main()
{
    derived1 d1;
    derived2 d2;

    call( d1 );
    call( d2 );
 }
```

The above code outputs:

> derived1!
>   derived2!

Comment: Your example will not compile. Neither `f()` nor `f_()` are `const` and cannot be invoked by `call` and `f_()` is `private` and cannot be accessed from `f()`.